# Given an input XML file , draw its tree structure

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

My task is to draw an xml tree from and XML file. I managed to open an xml file using openDialog component and now I have a saveDialog Componet which choose a file to write to. Now I have to think up an algorithm that would:

```
   <Videos>
     <Video> 
        <Title>The Distinguished Gentleman</Title>
        <Director>Jonathan Lynn</Director>
        <Actors>
           <Actor>Eddie Murphy</Actor>
           <Actor>Lane Smith</Actor>
           <Actor>Sheryl Lee Ralph</Actor>
           <Actor>Joe Don Baker</Actor>
        </Actors>
        <Length>112 Minutes</Length>
        <Format>DVD</Format>
        <Rating>R</Rating>
    </Video>
      <Video>
        <Title>Her Alibi</Title>
        <Director>Bruce Beresford</Director>
        <Length>94 Mins</Length>
        <Format>DVD</Format>
        <Rating>PG-13</Rating>
      </Video>
    </Videos>
```

So that would be:

```
    <Videos>
    ---<Video>
    -------<Title>
    -------<Director>
    -------<Actors>
    --------------<Actor>
    -------<Length>
    -------<Format>
    -------<Rating>
```

I assume that would be in foreach statement:

```
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(pathToXML);
    foreach (var element in XML.Descendants)
    {
       //code here ??

    }   ??
```

Yes, I know that. But I have problem how to select only one child node (no method for this). I have something like that , but still it lists all elements not only the structure:

```
    public string GetOutline(int indentLevel, XElement element)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();


        result = result.AppendLine(new string('-', indentLevel * 2) + element.Name);

        foreach (var childElement in element.Elements())

        {
            result.Append(GetOutline(indentLevel + 3, childElement));
        }

        return result.ToString();
```

Comment: Is there anything else we can do for you?

Comment: buy me a porsche ;) ?, I am trying to think it out, but I'm a beginner and not fluent in this yet

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finally LINQ to XML recursive viewing of elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423996/finally-linq-to-xml-recursive-viewing-of-elements)

Answer (score 2):

Recursively visit XElement nodes in the tree. For each element write the element name. Each time you visit the child node increase the indent so that you know how many '-' characters you want to write.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I have problem how to select only one child node (no method for this). I have something like that , but still it lists all elements not only the structure:

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I have problem how to select only one child node (no method for this). I have something like that , but still it lists all elements not only the structure. Could you look it up ?

Comment: What's wrong with `foreach(var element in currentElement.Children)`. Do you have `using System.Linq;` to get all the extension methods? Not sure why you need just one if there are many and also what would be the criterion to select one from many. I though you wanted to dump the whole tree.