# Finally LINQ to XML recursive viewing of elements

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

I have written:

```
        public string GetOutline(int indentLevel, XElement element)
        {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();


        result = result.AppendLine(new string('-', indentLevel * 2) + element.Name);

        foreach (var childElement in element.Elements())
        {
            result.Append(GetOutline(indentLevel + 3, childElement));
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }
```

The result of this recursive methond run on xml file shows:

```
    Videos
    ------Video
    ------------Title
    ------------Director
    ------------Actors
    ------------------Actor
    ------------------Actor
    ------------------Actor
    ------------------Actor
    ------------Length
    ------------Format
    ------------Rating
    ------Video
    ------------Title
    ------------Director
    ------------Length
    ------------Format
    ------------Rating
enter code here
```

But I would want the output to be like below:

```
    Videos
    ------Video
    ------------Title
    ------------Director
    ------------Actors
    ------------------Actor
    ------------Length
    ------------Format
    ------------Rating
```

How to edit the code ? Really struggling with this from yesterday ...

Comment: are you saying there is just one actor under actors,but still when the program runs you get four in the result

Comment: What is your intention for the output? Do you only want one element of each type at each level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use linq grouping by name:

```
foreach (var childElement in element.Elements().GroupBy(childElement => childElement.Name))
{
    result.Append(GetOutline(indentLevel + 3, childElement.First()));
}
```

instead of:

```
foreach (var childElement in element.Elements())
{
    result.Append(GetOutline(indentLevel + 3, childElement.First()));
}
```

---

The only problem of this method is the use of `First`.
If you have, for example in your XML file:

```
<actors>
    <actor>
        <property/>
    </actor>
    <actor>
        <differentProperty/>
        <differentProperty2/>
    </actor>
</actors>
```

With grouping and `First` the result will be:

```
actors
----actor
--------property
```

How do you want the result to appear in this case?

```
actors
----actor
--------property
--------differentProperty
--------differentProperty2
```

or

```
actors
----actor
--------property
----actor
--------differentProperty
--------differentProperty2
```

or this case will not appear?

#### UPDATE:

Given your comment the solution would be:

```
public static string GetOutline(int indentLevel, XElement element)
{
    return GetGroupOutline(indentLevel, new[] {element});
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns the outline of the elements that constitute a group.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="indentLevel">Indent level.</param>
/// <param name="elements">Elements of a group (all the element of the collection must have the same <c>Name</c>)</param>
/// <returns>Outline of the group.</returns>
private static string GetGroupOutline(int indentLevel, IEnumerable<XElement> elements)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    // Adds the group name in the outline
    result = result.AppendLine(new string('-', indentLevel * 6) + elements.First().Name);

    foreach (var childGroup in from element in elements  // Gets each element in the group "elements"
                               from childElement in element.Elements()  // Gets their children
                               group childElement by childElement.Name into childGroup  // Groups the children of all elements by their name to a new group called "childGroup"
                               select childGroup)
        result.Append(GetGroupOutline(indentLevel + 1, childGroup));  // Shows the outline of the group called "groupChild"

    return result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This does not answers the question

Comment: I would like to have:
        actors
        ----actor
        --------property
        --------differentProperty
        --------differentProperty2

Comment: This is great. Could you explain, it is a bit complicated now?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky because it works for me. but still a little complicated.

Comment: Given the fact that multiple elements can be "merged" into 1 title (it is the case for "actor"), the signature of your given function has to be changed to allow "multiple elements give 1 title in outline". This is why I've created GetGroupOutline.

GetGroupOutline returns the outline of the element of a group (I called a group, multiple XML elements that have the same name).

Comment: The question was not precise enough at that moment to have a complete answer.

Comment: I dont understand new[] {element} -> this creates the table of XElements ?
both anwsers are good, I dont know how to accept both answers.

Comment: new[] {element} just create an XElement[] array with 1 element : element.
The problem with the other answer is that it duplicates the whole tree  and loses the attributes of the elements (if your XML tree contains some attributes)

Answer (score 0):

You need to build xml tree with all unique elements first:

```
private XElement GetUniqueElementsOf(XDocument xdoc)
{
    XElement result = new XElement(xdoc.Root.Name);
    AddUniqueChildren(result, xdoc.Root);
    return result;
}

public void AddUniqueChildren(XElement dest, XElement source)
{
    foreach (XElement sourceChild in source.Elements())
    {
        var destChild = dest.Elements()
                            .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == sourceChild.Name);

        if (destChild == null)
        {
            destChild = new XElement(sourceChild.Name);
            dest.Add(destChild);
        }

        AddUniqueChilds(destChild, sourceChild);
    }
}
```

Second method will add all unique child elements to each node by recursively traversing xml. All you need to do at this point is output result:

```
 var result = GetOutline(0, GetUniqueElementsOf(XDocument.Load(path_to_xml)));
```

Outline method should be simple, without grouping (because we already have only unique elements of xml):

```
public string GetOutline(int indentLevel, XElement element)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    result = result.AppendLine(new string('-', indentLevel * 2) + element.Name);

    foreach (var childElement in element.Elements())            
        result.Append(GetOutline(indentLevel + 3, childElement));            

    return result.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
internal static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static List<XElement> Find(this XElement _objXElement, string _strFindXName)
    {
        List<XElement> _lsXElementsFound = new List<XElement>();
        try
        {
            List<XElement> _lsXElementsBundle = new List<XElement>();
            RecursiveSearch(_objXElement, _strFindXName, ref _lsXElementsBundle);
            if (_lsXElementsBundle != null && _lsXElementsBundle.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (XElement _objCurrentXElement in _lsXElementsBundle)
                {
                    if (_objCurrentXElement != null)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_objCurrentXElement.Value))
                        {
                            _lsXElementsFound.Add(_objCurrentXElement);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _objCurrentXElement.Value = string.Empty;
                            _lsXElementsFound.Add(_objCurrentXElement);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception _objException)
        {
            _lsXElementsFound = new List<XElement>();
            string _strDescription = NLOG.Utility.FormatEvent(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()
                , _objException.Message);
            NLOG.Log.Error(_strDescription);
        }
        return _lsXElementsFound;
    }

    #region "SUPPORT"

    private static void RecursiveSearch(XElement _objXElement, string _strFindXName
        , ref List<XElement> _lsOfXElementsFound)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_objXElement != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_strFindXName)
                && _lsOfXElementsFound != null)
            {
                if (_objXElement.Name == _strFindXName)
                {
                    _lsOfXElementsFound.Add(_objXElement);
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (XElement _objCurrentXElement in _objXElement.Elements())
                    {
                        RecursiveSearch(_objCurrentXElement, _strFindXName, ref _lsOfXElementsFound);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception _objException)
        {
            string _strDescription = NLOG.Utility.FormatEvent(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()
                , _objException.Message);
            NLOG.Log.Error(_strDescription);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: List<XElement> _ls = _objXElement.Find("Your XName");

Comment: Code only answers are usually [frowned upon](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258673/2596334). Try adding an [explination or code comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269981/2596334). Thanks.